# Outlook Email Notification VB code

Tags: outlook-2010

Found this code so that my meeting reminders overrider all current windows so im forced to see the notification. Hoping to set up something similar for every time i get an email notification. Currently it is pushed to the back and i don't even see it.

```
Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)


If TypeOf Item Is AppointmentItem Then
Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate
End If


End Sub
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Found the tutorial here

http://www.darthandy.com/2011/02/how-to-get-outlook-appointment.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    Application.ActiveExplorer.Activate
End Sub
```